# Can bounties be divided amongst answers?

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

After trawling through some of the [posts mentioning 'bounty'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty) & the [FAQ description of bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) I am still not clear if it possible to divide a bounty when rewarding it.

Is it possible to divide a bounty between different answers to a question?

Comment: Answer is no: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Bounty can be awarded to only one answer per question.

**After reading comments below -**

You cannot move the bounty once it is awarded to any particular answer.

**OLD ANSWER -**

<del>You can still move the bounty from one answer to another answer if you get a better answer in future after the bounty is awarded, but you cannot share a bounty for more than one answer.</del>

Comment: I think bounty award is only one time process we can not move it among answer like we do while accepting an answer. In simple word we can not award the same bounty again in question.

Comment: @Harry - I think you can move bounties just as you can move answers too unless some new change has been done in this regard.

Comment: You can't move bounties. You can move acceptance.

Comment: @ChrisF, @Harry - modified my answer as per your comments. I had thought that as we can move the acceptance, we can move bounties too. Thanks.